# Convert Document Object to XML Document JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I use a:

```
    $.ajax({  
      type: "GET",  
      url: someurl,  
      success: function(data) {  

      }  
    });
```

If someurl is appropriate, the it returns an XML, if not, it returns a String, which is why I dont specify the dataType parameter.

However, when I get back the XML, it looks like it is in a "Document" object. How do I get within the Document object to store the XML i need in javscript/jquery?

Comment: Since you don't provide a live example, you have to make your question very clear. This is confusing: "How do I get within the Document object to store the XML i need in javscript/jquery?". Please try to restate exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes I would suggest making a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the `$` (`jquery`) operator that works on a selector takes an optional second parameter which is the document on which you want to operate. For instance, `$('div', xmlDoc)`.